# Pandas - merge rows containing lists

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, group-by

I want to merge rows (kind of grouping by) but also merge their column data which in my case consists of a list.

For example, my data looks like:

```
Col1 Col2
a    [1,2,3]
a    [3,4,5]
b    [1,2,3,4,20]
b    [3,80,4,5]
```

And the resulted dataframe would be:

```
Col1 Col2
a    [1,2,3,4,5]
b    [1,2,3,4,20,80,5]
```

Comment: Should the repeated values need to be eliminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','a','b','b'], 'col2': [[1,2,3], [3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,20], [3,80,4,5]]})
print(df.groupby('col1').sum())
```

Output:

```
                               col2
col1                               
a                [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
b     [1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 3, 80, 4, 5]
```

---

If it is required to consider the repeated value only once then it can be done in the following two way:
**1) Using Set()**

```
print(df.groupby('col1').sum()['col2'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  col1                     col2
0    a          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1    b  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 80, 20]
```

2) **By using dict.fromkeys():** This will help to keep the order of elements in the list:

```
print(df.groupby('col1').sum()['col2'].apply(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x))).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  col1                     col2
0    a          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1    b  [1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 80, 5]
```